# Can I get the updated DB changes without restarting my local server in JAVA web project?

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a JAVA web application and i have mysql as my backend. I make DB calls from my application. But whenever i make any change in DB, my local server has to be restarted to redeploy my java EAR for the updated DB changes to be reflected, Is there a way i can get the updated DB changes without restarting my local server?

Please let me know.

Comment: I'll assume that changes means schema changes, not mere data inserts or updates.  You shouldn't have to restart the server unless you point to a new database.  In that case you must, because JNDI lookups have to be updated.

Comment: Just (auto)commit the queries. Exact answer depends on persistence framework being used, which is absent in the information provided so far. It has at least nothing to do with JSP/Servlets as those are basically merely a HTML output generator and a HTTP request controller, not a persistence framework (only e.g. JDBC and JPA are).

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to restart your local server unless and until you want to change the `database` mean you want to point to entirely different database schema.
And if you want to change i.e adding extra columns to the database then also it will work fine but if you delete columns or table from current schema then only you need to change your code and start your server again.

**Note :-**

In case if you are working with Dynamic Web Project in eclipse with Tomcat server configured within then you don't need to do that also because server will reload your project after some time automatically.

Comment: You're not answering why OP needs to restart his server everytime and how to solve it.